# getting nested list within model

Tags: c#

I have two object models that looks like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
   public List<SomeOtherObject> TheListOfSomeOtherObjects { get; set; }
}

public class SomeOtherObject
{
   long SomeOtherObjectID { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a list of `MyObjects` called `ListOfMyObjects` from which I want to extract all the `SomeOtherObjectID` that are inside lists `TheListOfSomeOtherObjects`

I want to write something like this:

```
var ListOfAllSomeOtherObjectID = (from l in ListOfMyObjects
                           select l.SomeOtherObject.SomeOtherObjectID ).ToList();
```

It's not working because of the syntax. How do I get a list of the nested lists?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to flatten the nested lists:

```
var allChildren = myObjects.SelectMany(o => o.ChildObjects).ToList();
```

If you then want to get a property of those objects, you'll need a separate `Select()` call:

```
var allChildren = myObjects.SelectMany(o => o.ChildObjects)
                           .Select(c => c.SomeProperty)
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: Actually, I want the SomeOtherObjectID of all the children. I tried (o => 0.ChildObject.SomeOtherObjectID) but it's not accepting it.

Comment: ok, got it, thanks for the  answer; now I know how SelectMany works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below:

```
var ids = l.SelectMany(o => o.TheListOfSomeOtherObjects).Select(o => o.SomeOtherObjectID);
```

The `SelectMany` creates a flattened list from the list of lists.

Add a `ToList()` if you want a list.

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
var listSOOIds = listOfMyObjects.TheListOfSomeOtherObjects.Select(s => s.SomeOtherObjectID).ToList();
```